# Autoloading defcustoms: good practice or not?

Tags: autoload, defcustom

In my init file, I often find myself trying to set a customizable variable *before* the file (usually a mode of some sort) is loaded. This, of course, results in an error.

While this problem could be addressed through [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) and other means, it seems that making autoloading customizable variables should be a general good practice.

Customizable variables are by definition part of the user interface of a package. Packages tend to autoload functions (e.g. `foo-mode`) that users are expected to invoke directly--why not customizable variables as well?

Is there any problem with autoloading customizable variables?

Comment: What error do you see? You can set customizable variables with `setq` before they are defined without any problems.

Comment: What @Tyler says is true, of course. Did you really get an error, or did you just have trouble trying to find such an option - e.g., by `C-h v`?

Comment: I'm not always using `setq` first. E.g. when adding to a list, I often `(cl-pushnew x my-list)`, which errors if `my-list` is not defined. The solution is to wrap everything in `with-eval-after-load`, but I don't care for that /shrug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been discussed more than once on `emacs-devel@gnu.org`.

- [Here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-05/msg00415.html) is one such thread, from 2016.
- And [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-11/msg00791.html) is something from Stefan, who dislikes such autoloading, from 2014.
- Likewise, Glenn, in [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-08/msg01386.html) 2010 thread.
- And Stefan again, in [2009](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-11/msg00516.html).
- And here is an earlier [2009](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2009-01/msg00117.html) thread about it.

There are many more such discussions, going back further.

One reason given against is that the autoload file gets bloated.

Another reason, more practical, is that it can be problematic if the definition (e.g. the initial value or something used in `:initialize`) depends on other things in the library being loaded first.

Personally, I happen to favor autoloading defcustoms, generally.  It's about discovery.

Comment: +1 on the benefit of *discovery*. And shouldn't `:intialize` *not* depend on load order of things?

Comment: `:initialize` is a function. It could check some variable or try to use some function that will be defined after the file is loaded. But yes, clearly one doesn't want to couple things like that. Better to avoid that.